# toc in a github_document

Tags: r-markdown, tableofcontents

I am trying to add a table of contents to my rmd github_document, however I cannot get this to work. I am on R version 3.5.2 and following the [documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/github_document_format.html#table_of_contents) I have:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  github_document:
    toc: true
---

# header 1
# header 2
# header 3
```

but the toc does not appear in the md:

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that afaik, GitHub Flavored Markdown does not support that syntax on its own. I'm not familiar with R Markdown, but you may need to translate/compile your R Markdown to GitHub Flavored Markdown in order for it to render properly on GitHub.

Comment: Doesn't look like a coding issue. Your code sample runs fine for me, locally and on GitHub. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with your older version of R. I'm using R version 4.1.2.